# Declaring 2D Vector in Global Scope gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, graph

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n;
std::vector<bool> visited(n,false);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> g(n,std::vector<int>(n));


int main() {
    cin>>n;
    //std::vector<std::vector<int>> g(n,std::vector<int>(n));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cin>>g[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<g[0][0];

}
```

2D vector declared inside main function gives no error but when declared in global scope gives SIGSEV error

Comment: What do you think is the value of `n` when the vector is constructed? Don't assume the compiler would automagically delay intialization until after you assigned somethin to `n`.

Comment: @churill  I pass values using input.txt , map <F9> :!g++ -g % -o %:r && ./%:r < input.txt <CR>  ,  Can you please be more verbose on this why error occurs in global scope and not when declared inside main? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but t `g` will be constructed before reading `n`. At the pint of contruction `n` contains an indeterminate value. Maybe less than zero, maybe too large to fit into memory. Your program has undefined behaviour. When declared in `main` you get the correct order. That is 1.) Read `n` 2.) construct `g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `visited` and `g` get initialized, the value of `n` is `0`. (`n` is declared in global namespace and will be [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).) So the `vector`s are empty and contain no elements. Then access to them like `g[0][0]` leads to UB.

On the other hand, for the vector `g` declared in `main()`, `n` is set to some value and then used to initialize `g`, then `g` is initialized as containing `n` elements.